# Multiple "dragenter" targets/classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use the Jquery "dragenter" event on multiple targets/classes?

Is this the correct way?

```
$('.list').on('dragenter','.class1, .class2', function(e) { ...
```

I´m asking because this won´t work.
But maby there is another error in the code!
I couldn´t find any information about multiple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see a reason why it should not work, see a similar example here:

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('.list').on('dragenter drop dragover','.class1, .class2', 
      function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.type=='dragenter')
          $('.out').append(this.innerHTML+' ');})
});
```

```css
.class1,.class2 {height: 100px;
           width: 300px;
           border: 1px solid red;}
.out {position:absolute; top:0px; left:330px; width=300px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
 <div class="class1">one</div>
 <div class="class2">two</div>
</div>
<div class="out"></div>
```

In this example you can see that even multiple events can be bound to multiple classes. In the actual callback function I then filter out the only event I want output for ("dragenter").

If you want to avoid the default behaviour (i. e. the browser changes to the location of the dragged file) you should at least call the event-method `e.preventDefault()` for all three possible events `dragenter`,`dragover` and `drop`. Calling `e.stopPropagation()` can also be useful in some situations but is not necessary in this example.